# bei + Nominativ in this sentence?

Tags: nominative

> Die Nase ist das bei Wirbeltieren meist mittig im Gesichtsfeld angelegte Riechorgan, das bei Mensch wie Tier häufig auch Teil des Atmungsapparats ist.

Why is the word "bei" here used with nominative case? Or is it some kind of set phrases?

Also, if I search on Context Reverso with the term "bei Mensch", there are also [many sentences](https://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/bei+Mensch) where the usage is similar.

Comment: @CarstenS okay, I will put them as text. Thanks!

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion there's a nominative? There isn't.

Comment: Why isn't it? For singular "der Mensch", there is only one form with "Mensch", since it is a "n-Deklination" noun, any other form is ["Menschen"](https://www.verbformen.de/?w=Mensch). Or maybe there is any irregular rule that I haven't know yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two phenomena come together here:

1. When two or more nouns are connected with "und" or "(so)wie", the articles can be left out (Duden-Grammatik #391):

> bei Mensch und Tier
> mit Nadel und Faden
> über Berg und Tal
> Papierloses Büro, Prozesssteuerung und Digitalisierung sind für Unternehmen und Behörden manchmal immer noch Herausforderung und Reizwort.

2. Moreover, when you have a weakly declined noun (like *Mensch*) in singular without an article, the ending -en is omitted in order to avoid confusion with the plural (Duden-Grammatik #1531).

Exploratory examples:

Plural, nominative case, 2x article *die* left out:

> Menschen und Tiere schwitzen im Sommer.

Singular, nominative case , articles *der* and *das* left out:

> Mensch und Tier schwitzen im Sommer.

Plural, dative case, 2x article *den* left out:

> Die Nase ist bei Menschen wie Tieren Teil des Atmungsapparats.

Singular, dative case, 2x article *dem* left out, 1x ending -en left out to avoid confusion with the above plural:

> Die Nase ist bei Mensch wie Tier Teil des Atmungsapparats.

Without omissions, it is:

> Die Nase ist bei dem Menschen wie dem Tier Teil des Atmungsapparats.

Source (in German) and a bit of further reading:

https://blog.leo.org/2022/03/22/fuer-mensch-und-tier-wo-sind-artikel-und-endung-geblieben/

Comment: Fascinating. You could include examples of accusative and dative objects such as «ich sehe Mensch und Tier im Sommer schwitzen» or «Mensch und Tier fliesst im Sommer der Schweiss hinunter».

Comment: richtig geil. Danke!